# Питон. Генерация всех сбалансированных сочетаний скобок

Tags: python, python-3.x, соревнование

**Условие**

Нужно написать функцию, которая генерирует полный список "сбалансированных" сочетаний из `n` пар скобок. Сбалансированное сочетание — это сочетание, при котором у каждой открывающей скобки должна быть соответствующая ей закрывающая скобка, причем закрывающая скобка не должна идти впереди соответствующей открывающей.

**Входные данные:**

На вход подается положительное целое число от 0 до 15 (собственно, `n`) (тип `int`).

**Выходные данные**

На выходе должен быть полный список строк сбалансированных скобок (тип `list`) (см. примеры).

**Примеры:**

`0 => [""]`

`1 => ["()"]`

`2 => ["()()","(())"]`

`3 => ["()()()","(())()","()(())","(()())","((()))"]`

**Критерий оценивания:**

Язык соревнования — Питон 3.

В соревновании победит *самое быстрое* решение.

**Источник:**

Источником послужила задача с *Codewars*  [All Balanced Parentheses](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5426d7a2c2c7784365000783) 4 кю сложности.

**P. S.**

Если я как-то неправильно оформил соревнование — с радостью приму правки и уточнения.

**UPD:**
Для прогонки времени использовался следующий код:

```
import time

def count_time(function, f_arg, how_many_times):
    a = time.time()
    for i in range(how_many_times):
        function(f_arg)
    b = (time.time() - a) / how_many_times
    return b
```

**Итоги:**

- Первое решение @MBo: 26.08478112220764 c.
- Второе решение @MBo: (поверил, проверять не стал, будем считать, что 10000 с. )
- Первое решение @StanislavVolodarskiy: (на 6 итерации комп завис и алгоритм не завершился)
- Второе решение @StanislavVolodarskiy: 4.338251447677612 c.

Итого побеждает итеративное построение по свойству StanislavVolodarskiy! Его ответ принимаю.

Comment: "В соревновании победит самое быстрое решение." - ну, такое. Во-первых не понятно кто и как будет замерять, и как это проверить. Результат будет скорее вероятностный, а не точный. Ну и в итоге выиграет решение на машинном коде вшитом в Python, а не на Python.

Comment: @insolor, и что же делать?

Comment: Время в основном обусловлено построением строк и списка для вывода, т.е. работой с памятью.

Comment: Да, перед задачей стоило бы оценить возможность генерации и вывода списка вариантов для 500 пар ;-)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, изменил, теперь числа до 20.

Comment: Задача звучала бы более корректно, если бы вы попросили распечатать последовательности или сделать генератор, без требования сохранять результат в списке.

Comment: @Глеб например, не сравнивать время. Обычно соревнования (классический код-гольф) делают по размеру кода — это по крайней мере легко объективно и точно измерить. По времени теоретически тоже можно, но должен быть арбитр, который все ответы ответ прогонит много раз вперемешку с другими ответами на одной и той же машине, и средний результат посчитает. Если вы готовы взять на себя роль арбитра по окончании соревнования — то ок. Но у вас фактически соревнование не ограничено по времени, так что потенциально количество участников не ограничено, и это большая проблема для потенциального арбитра.

Comment: @insolor, а теперь правила не поздно изменить?

Comment: @Глеб менять условие победы - я бы сказал что поздно. Ограничить время действия конкурса - думаю еще нет.

Comment: Я бы сказал что менять условия сейчас ещё не поздно. Текущие ответы от этого не испортятся. Код-гольф, правда, мне менее интересен. Решить задачу быстро и в ограниченной памяти - практическая задача. Решить задачу минимальным кодом - приводит к довольно страшным результатом. Так или иначе, вопрос можно менять.

Comment: Ладно, ничего уже менять уже не буду. Проверку на время буду делать следующим образом: каждое присланное решение буду 10 раз прогонять на своем компе для n = 15 (без печати) и вычислять среднее арифметическое. Так пойдет?

Comment: @insolor, время соревнования я ограничу до воскресенья. В воскресенье буду подводить итоги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекурсивное построение по определению правильной скобочной последовательности. Для ускорения рекурсии хвосты из последних двенадцати символов кэшированы. Объём кэша не превосходит 50 килобайт (*12·2<sup>12</sup>*).

```
def parens_search(n, cb):
    m = min(n, 12) + 1
    tails = [[None] * m for _ in range(m)]
    tails[0] = [[')' * r] for r in range(m)]

    for l in range(1, m):
        for r in range(l, m - l):
            tails[l][r] = []
            if r > l:
                tails[l][r].extend(')' + t for t in tails[l][r - 1])
            if l > 0:
                tails[l][r].extend('(' + t for t in tails[l - 1][r])

    def rec(head, l, r):
        if l + r < m:
            for t in tails[l][r]:
                cb(head + t)
        else:
            if r > l:
                rec(head + ')', l, r - 1)
            if l > 0:
                rec(head + '(', l - 1, r)

    rec('', n, n)


def parens(n):
    result = []
    parens_search(n, result.append)
    return result
```

> ```
>     n       15    16    17
> время (c)  1.3   4.8  17.3
> ```

Итеративное построение [по cвойству](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0):

```
def parens(n):
    parens = [['']]
    for m in range(1, n + 1):
        parens.append([
            f'({lhs}){rhs}'
            for i in range(m)
            for lhs in parens[i]
            for rhs in parens[m - i - 1]
        ])
    return parens[-1]
```

> ```
>     n       15    16    17
> время (c)  2.3   8.3  29.6
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Для затравки. 13 секунд на генерацию 10 миллионов вариантов при n=15.

Использован алгоритм нахождения следующей в лексикографическом порядке перестановки ([вот аналог](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/bracket_sequences#6))

Ищется самая правая открывающая скобка, которую можно заменить на закрывающую без нарушения правильности баланса (количество закрывающих в любом префиксе не должно превышать количество открывающих). За подсчёт баланса в правой части отвечает переменная `bal`. Если она больше нуля, то справа закрывающих скобок больше, а слева соответственно открывающих больше, и тогда текущую открывающую можно поменять на закрывающую. После этого добавляем лексикографически минимальный суффикс из набора открывающих (их количество рассчитывается из баланса), затем - набора закрывающих скобок.

```
import time
def next_seq(s, n):
    bal = 0
    for i in reversed(range(2*n)):
        if s[i] == "(":
            bal -= 1
            if bal:
                op = n-(i+bal)//2
                cl = 2*n-i-1 - op
                return s[:i] + ')' + "("*op + ")"*cl
        else:
            bal += 1
    return ""

n = 15
res = []
t = time.time()
s = "("*n + ")"*n
while s:
    res.append(s)
    s = next_seq(s, n)
print(time.time()-t, len(res))
#print(res)
```

Вывод при n=3:

```
['((()))', '(()())', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()']
```

До кучи: сделал генерацию бинарных слов, соответствующих валидным скобочным последовательностям, по Кнуту, но оно ни фига не быстрое, даже без формирования строк

```
def next_p(x):
    m0 = 0xFFFFFFFF // 3
    t = x ^ m0
    if ((t&x)==0):
        return 0
    u = (t-1) ^ t
    v = x | u
    y = (u & m0).bit_count()
    #y = bin(u & m0).count("1")   #до Python 3.10
    w = v + 1
    t = v & ~w
    y = t >> y
    y += w
    return y

def p2str(x):
    s, j = 0, 0
    res = []
    while x:
        s += -1 + 2*(x&1)
        res.append(")("[x&1])
        x >>= 1
        j += 1
    res = "".join(res)
    res += ")"*s
    return res

x = (1<<n) - 1
while x:
    #print(p2str(x))
    #res.append(p2str(x))
    x = next_p(x)
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы объяснить принцип работы функции `next_seq`? Там очень сложный алгоритм, не пойму никак.

Comment: @Глеб Да, нетривиальный, добавил описание.